# Unable to get correct base for cracking Crypt3 SHA-512 on Linux with Python

Tags: hash, password-cracking, python

I am reading a book and it gives me a simple Python script to crack `/etc/shadow` passwords that were encrypted with the `crypt()` function. It then challenges you to amend the Python program to work with the newer Crypt3 SHA-512 algorithm used in modern Linux(es).

I am getting stuck on outputting the same hash that is stored in `/etc/shadow`. I have a user `test1` with a password of `password` and `/etc/shadow` looks like this:

```
cat /etc/shadow | grep test1
test1:$6$sRgBNCzw$A3IHWJz./hdhPa1FHuN.Kn.P/2InPqGjZxxGnNUxY2I2b0t4xpogCKWkq9.Ra.XDaFSpNOb5UYhwjQMzBWrtp.:16792:0:99999:7:::
```

An the simplest form of my script looks like this:

```
import hashlib
dk = hashlib.pbkdf2_hmac('sha512',b'password',b'sRgBNCzw',5000)
```

Inspecting `dk` looks like this:

```
>>> dk
'.YQ\xf0\xf1\x1f\x08\x0e\x9c\xa9-E\x90\x89\xebZ\xb1\x04ao:\x00;\x9a\xcb?\xaa\x04H\x14\xb6&\x9c\x0e}#\xbd\xf5\xe6\xa5\xd6\xda|xu\x1e\xa1\xd1\x95D\x94\x15\x19 \xccEX\\\xf0g\x97|\\\xee'
```

Which I guess is Python's best effort at representing a binary blob as text. However, I need to compare this with the hashed value of the Crypt3 function which is:

```
A3IHWJz./hdhPa1FHuN.Kn.P/2InPqGjZxxGnNUxY2I2b0t4xpogCKWkq9.Ra.XDaFSpNOb5UYhwjQMzBWrtp.
```

Now just looking at the hashed value in the shadow file I can see it looks like base64 so I use this:

```
binascii.b2a_base64(binascii.hexlify(dk))
```

And get this:

```
'MmU1OTUxZjBmMTFmMDgwZTljYTkyZDQ1OTA4OWViNWFiMTA0NjE2ZjNhMDAzYjlhY2IzZmFhMDQ0ODE0YjYyNjljMGU3ZDIzYmRmNWU2YTVkNmRhN2M3ODc1MWVhMWQxOTU0NDk0MTUxOTIwY2M0NTU4NWNmMDY3OTc3YzVjZWU=\n'
```

Further reading has taught me that the Crypt3 function uses a slightly modified version of base64 that does away with padding and '='.

Can any one help with how I can get my hash to match the hash in `/etc/shadow` using Python?

Comment: Have you seen https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/158400/etc-shadow-how-to-generate-6-s-encrypted-password? It looks like it's generating the same `$6$` type that you are even though it's using a different algorithm.

Comment: 'violent python' is my guess for the book? At least that's the one that brought me here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on information in [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/158400/etc-shadow-how-to-generate-6-s-encrypted-password), I was able to successfully reproduce a hash.

After setting my password to `password`, I executed these commands

```
$ sudo grep neil /etc/shadow
neil:$6$GpNiWKnm$aToSshPrg45wXFuP/Hmkkpf8/GUYg0d/C4eU/BH7iG2QwM.C59NIVr/izGUGXzf7HjqQNmpFXhxtIxGtXNrmj0:16793:0:99999:7:::
$ python -c 'import crypt; print crypt.crypt("password", "$6$GpNiWKnm$")'
$6$GpNiWKnm$aToSshPrg45wXFuP/Hmkkpf8/GUYg0d/C4eU/BH7iG2QwM.C59NIVr/izGUGXzf7HjqQNmpFXhxtIxGtXNrmj0
$ python --version
Python 2.7.10
```

It should be noted that the hash algorithm that is in use can be determined by the value between the first pair of dollar signs. In this case the `$6$` means it's sha-512 ([reference](http://www.aychedee.com/2012/03/14/etc_shadow-password-hash-formats/)).

Comment: Thanks Neil yes this works great. I was blinkerd by hashlib.